Add edges that begin from network nodes and lead to nothing?
Can I add edges with arrows that begin from nodes 4 5 6 7 and lead to nothing? Just 4 straight lines.
library(visNetwork)
# Create nodes data frame
nodes <- data.frame(
  id = 1:7,
  label = c("BLADDER", "TRODELVY", "EV", "NO ADC RECEIVED", "EV", "NO ADC RECEIVED", "TRODELVY "),
  color = c("gray", "red", "blue", "gray", "blue", "gray", "red"),
  shape = "box",
  level = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
)

# Create edges data frame
edges <- data.frame(
  from = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
  to = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
)

# Create the network visualization
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visNodes(shape = "square", size = 500, font = list(color = "white")) %>%
  visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE)%>%
  visHierarchicalLayout(levelSeparation = 200, direction = "LR")


Aren't edges, conceptually/computationally considered (line) segments rather than lines (un-directed)  and as lines what might their length or angle from origin be? Which is to say, you might be able to but would it server? Or is the idea that such lines might represent 'something;, a place holder perhaps for something as yet unknown?

Introduce another node, create edges from those points to that node, either make it invisible or label it "nothing".

As Chris noted, edges always connect two nodes (or one node to itself), so you cannot create an edge that leads "nowhere".
You can probably create something that visually looks like an edge that leads nowhere, by making the node it ends at invisible (alpha = 0) or otherwise indistinguishable from the background.
An alternative could be simply adding an arrow that starts at a node and ends at a certain point in the coordinate system, but this is not an edge and I am not sure if visNetwork supports this.
